# AJAX Request with an Event Loop

Tags: javascript, ajax, loops, for-loop, events

I'm looking to create a function that runs an AJAX request with an event loop. It's intended to take these 9 inputs at the top, and run through an event loop to AJAX request them from a database. For now I just have it doing console.log but eventually would have it do some other cool stuff. However it does not work and I get an error "undefined", so I'm curious what I am missing?

```js
var cards = [
  "Black Lotus",
  "Mox Pearl",
  "Mox Sapphire",
  "Mox Jet",
  "Mox Ruby",
  "Mox Emerald",
  "Time Walk",
  "Timetwister",
  "Ancestral Recall",
];

for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
  function renderBinder() {
    var cardName = cards[i];

    var queryURL = "https://api.scryfall.com/cards/named?fuzzy=" + cardName;

    $.ajax({
      url: queryURL,

      method: "GET",
    }).then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.name);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Where specifically are you getting the undefined from? Your code doesn''t show calling the renderBinder function also. You can edit the question any time to update clarifications. Your issue is most likely `i` undefined inside the function and passing `cardName` into the function would solve that issue

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sequentially make AJAX requests with different cards each time, you could do something like this. The function `getCardDetails` takes in an array of cards as input. It removes a card from the list and makes an AJAX call, on success of that call we call the same function again, this time the input array will not have the card for which already call was made.

```js
var cards = [
  "Black Lotus",
  "Mox Pearl",
  "Mox Sapphire",
  "Mox Jet",
  "Mox Ruby",
  "Mox Emerald",
  "Time Walk",
  "Timetwister",
  "Ancestral Recall",
];

function getCardDetails (cards) {
    if (cards.length) {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: "https://api.scryfall.com/cards/named?fuzzy=" + cards.pop()
        })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            getCardDetails(cards);
        });
    }
}

getCardDetails(cards); // Logs the response of each request
```